# Determine convexity of discrete $L_k$ from $\frac{L_{k+1}}{L_k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, convex-analysis

I am currently reading "Gems of theoretical computer science" and in the chapter about superconcentrators I don't understand an argument about convexity.

There it is tried to show that some graph exists by the probabilistic method. To show that, the goal is to show that the sum $\sum_{k=3}^{3m} L_k$ with $L_k =\frac{\binom{9k}{6k}}{\binom{26m}{4k}}$ is smaller than 1. For that they want to show that $L_k$ as a function of $k$ is convex so either $L_3$ or $L_{3m}$ is the largest element in this sum and can be used to bound this sum, which all makes sense.

Problematic becomes proving convexity. There is no definition of convexity in the book, but the one that I know is $f(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) \leq \theta f(x) + (1-\theta) f(y)$

The hint tells that one should evaluate $\frac{L_{k+1}}{L_k}$ to determine convexity. For this I unfold the binomial coefficients and can cancel some terms out. But then I got stuck.

According to the solution one can group the resulting fraction to a product where each term is monotone increasing and conclude that $\frac{L_{k+1}}{L_k}$ is monotone increasing, so that means $\frac{L_{k+1}}{L_k} \geq \frac{L_k}{L_{k-1}}$ or alternatively $\frac{L_{k+1} L_{k-1}}{L_k^2} \geq 1$.

This makes sense, but then they simply conlude that $L_k$ must be convex. I don't see how to combine this with the defintion I know. This function is discrete, but I have seen that there is an real-valued continuation of the binomial coefficient to use. But we only look at those values that are placed in distance 1 and not every $\theta$ as above.

How to combine these facts to conclude this ?